# What does @something@ refer to

Tags: bash, grep, sh

I was reading the `grep` source code and found `egrep.sh` with the below content:

```
#!@SHELL@                          
grep=grep                          
case $0 in                         
  */*)                             
    dir=${0%/*}                    
    if test -x "$dir/@grep@"; then 
      PATH=$dir:$PATH              
      grep=@grep@                  
    fi;;                           
esac                               
exec $grep @option@ "$@"
```

I don't seem to understand how `@SHELL@` `@grep@` and `@option@` works or even what they do in the context they are used

Referenced source is located at: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/egrep.sh

Comment: They're probably getting replaced with `sed` or a similar tool at some point in the build (eg: `sed s#@SHELL@#/bin/bash#`).  Can you link to the version you're looking at?

Comment: @CarlNorum posted the [link](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/egrep.sh) to the source

Comment: @CarlNorum you are right, I did not check the `Makefile`

Comment: That Makefile has `sed -e 's|[@]SHELL@|$(SHELL)|g'     \
     -e "$$edit_substring"     \
     -e "s|[@]grep@|$$grep|g"     \
     -e "s|[@]option@|$$option|g" <$(srcdir)/egrep.sh >$@-t` :)

Comment: I would probably delete this question, as I seem to have found the answer

Comment: Why don't you post and accept your own answer? No need to delete the question. It's a good one.

Comment: That file should be named, "egrep.sh.in" or something ".in".  Files that get configured are traditionally named, "foo.in" and the substitution (sedding) is used to "configure" the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I read the [`Makefile`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/Makefile.am) and found that the `@something@` were placeholders to be substituted with `sed` as below:

```
sed -e 's|[@]SHELL@|$(SHELL)|g'                 \
    -e "$$edit_substring"                   \
    -e "s|[@]grep@|$$grep|g"                    \
    -e "s|[@]option@|$$option|g" <$(srcdir)/egrep.sh >$@-t
$(AM_V_at)chmod a=rx $@-t
$(AM_V_at)mv $@-t $@
```